# React native bug image shows blank

Tags: react-native

I have a simple react-native application that loads images in a component. The component uses the standard Image component.

```
 <Image source={this.state.ImageSource} style={styles.image} />
```

I have the following code that initializes ImageSource.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ImageSource: {uri: this.props.imageurl}});
}
```

Image source is an object with uri, e.g., `{ uri: 'http://localip:123/controller/imageaction/imageid'}`.

Images that are less that 1MB in size load without problems. Images that are 1MB or more seem to have issues where they render as a blank image for seeminly forever.

I tried using package react-native-image-progress, and it has the same behavior, similarly failing for bigger images where the loading indicator keeps showing...

I am testing on a slow lower-end LG dumb smart-phone with Android 4.1.2. But in Google Chrome browser, this very phone is able to show large and small images without a problem.

I tried to fix this using android:largeHeap="true" but that didn't cause any change in behavior. Shrinking images makes them able to load, but I need to display big images as well as small.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ImageSource:this.props.imageurl});
}

<Image source={{uri: this.state.ImageSource}} style={{width: 400, height: 400}}/>
```

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thanks for your reply. I tried many combinations for setting the source, including hard-coded URIs for testing, and the problem still happened. I'm sure that it's not because of the way I'm settings source. The styles.image object also contains width and height.

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html try to replicate the same by using the url. And then modify the code base on ur requirement. If this works it means there is no problem in ur code. Or share the url I will try to load in my sample.